# Why is my SQL failing? (ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Why is my SQL failing? I think it s formatted correctly, but it throws an error at me.

```
    INSERT INTO NBOT_USERS
       (ID,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME)
    VALUES
       (1002, 'Smith', 'John')
    WHERE 1002 NOT IN (SELECT IT_ID FROM NBOT_USERS);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Inserting Values with a Subquery: Example](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_9014.htm#i2126076)

```
INSERT INTO bonuses
   SELECT employee_id, salary*1.1 
   FROM employees
   WHERE commission_pct > 0.25 * salary;
```

With your schema:

```
INSERT INTO NBOT_USERS (ID,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME)
Select 1002, 'Smith', 'John' 
  From dual
  WHERE 1002 NOT IN (SELECT  FROM NBOT_USERS);
```

Answer (score 4):

Insert queries do not have where clauses, unless you're doing `INSERT ... SELECT FROM`, in which case there can be a where clause in the SELECT portion.

Comment: So how can I do a conditional? Like...only allow to insert if the ID does not yet exist in the table? (it is NOT a PK, PK is actually a sequenced number so it is not shown here)

Comment: select to see if the ID exists, insert if it doesn't. you'll have to apply some locks as well to prevent any parallel processes from poaching the ID out from under you.

Comment: I am not sure what the syntax for that would be, could you please provide a short example?