# SQL to insert only if a certain value is NOT already present in the table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

How to insert a number into the table, only if the table does not already have that number in it?

I am looking for specific SQL code, not really sure how to approach this. Tried several things, nothing's working.

**EDIT**

Table looks like this:

```
PK   ID    Value
1     4     500
2     9     3
```

So if I am trying to `INSERT (ID, Value) VALUES (4,100)` it should not try to do it!

Comment: Can't tell you unless you show what the table looks like

Comment: Basically a rephrased version of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156931/why-is-my-sql-failing-ora-00933-sql-command-not-properly-ended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try MERGE statement:

```
MERGE INTO tbl USING
    (SELECT 4 id, 100 value FROM dual) data
ON (data.id = tbl.id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, value) VALUES (data.id, data.value)
```

Comment: ORA-00969: missing ON keyword

Comment: I've written it from my memory, I don't have access to the oracle db right now. Try to change ON condition to `[...]ON (data.id = tbl.id)
WHEN[...]`. This is the only possible mistake I can se right now.
You can also check [this link](http://psoug.org/reference/merge.html) for more examples.

Comment: Yes, I believe the problem is that you must have `()`'s around the ON condition...  I've edited the answer, but it must be reviewed since I don't have enough rep yet.  :)

Answer (score 5):

If `ID` is supposed to be unique, there should be a unique constraint defined on the table.  That will throw an error if you try to insert a value that already exists

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD CONSTRAINT uk_id UNIQUE( id );
```

You can catch the error and do whatever you'd like if an attempt is made to insert a duplicate key-- anything from ignoring the error to logging and re-raising the exception to raising a custom exception

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table_name( id, value ) 
    VALUES( 4, 100 );
EXCEPTION
  WHEN dup_val_on_index
  THEN
    <<do something>>
END;
```

You can also code the `INSERT` so that it inserts 0 rows (you would still want the unique constraint in place both from a data model standpoint and because it gives the optimizer more information and may make future queries more efficient)

```
INSERT INTO table_name( id, value )
  SELECT 4, 100
    FROM dual
   WHERE NOT EXISTS( 
    SELECT 1
      FROM table_name
     WHERE id = 4 )
```

Or you could code a `MERGE` instead so that you update the `VALUE` column from 500 to 100 rather than inserting a new row.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE (YOUR_FIELD)
SELECT '1' FROM YOUR_TABLE YT WHERE YT.YOUR_FIELD <> '1' LIMIT 1
```

Of course, that '1' will be your number or your variable.
You can use INSERT + SELECT to solve this problem.

Comment: Doesn't work - still inserts though the number is already in there.

Comment: It would work only if there will be one row in the table.
`INSERT INTO tbl (ID, Value) SELECT 4, 100 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl WHERE ID = 4)` should work though.